# Displaying Navigation drawer in all activities problem

Tags: android-activity, navigation, click, drawer

I'm making a navigation drawer with different activities and i want to display the same navigation drawer in all activities , i take the same code and put it in all activities but when i click on the activities my app crashes all the time i don't know why

Comment: could you please share your code so we can help? anyway below is the example that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for displaying Navigation drawer on all activity, hope this example help...!

**BaseActivity**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    ArrayList<String> menuList;

    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    protected ListView mDrawerList;
    protected static int position;
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);
        prepareListItems();


        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, menuList));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
            }
        });

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                        /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,     /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.open_drawer,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.close_drawer)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */ {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        if (isLaunch) {
            isLaunch = false;
            openActivity(1);
        }

    }

    private void prepareListItems() {
        menuList = new ArrayList<>();
        menuList.add(" Activity1 ");
        menuList.add(" Activity2 ");
        menuList.add(" Activity3 ");
        menuList.add(" Activity4 ");
    }

    /**
     * @param position Launching activity when any list item is clicked.
     */
    protected void openActivity(int position) {
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position - 1, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.


        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity1.class));
                break;
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));
                break;
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity3.class));
                break;
            case 4:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity4.class));
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

//        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

**Activity1**

```
public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, frameLayout);
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**navigation_drawer_base_layout**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/simple_brushed_metal"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**header**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shade">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/developed_by_nd_software_solution"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/textColorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**drawer_list_item**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary" />
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

 <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Here I have provided code for one activity (Activity1), write code for other activities like Activity2, Activity3 etc.